# How to change caps lock key to backspace?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-layout

I use Windows 10. How can I change the caps lock key to do backspace?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I used this registry key

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
 
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,03,00,00,00,0E,00,3a,00,3a,00,46,00,00,00,00,00
```

Comment: There are a lot of shady results on a web search about this; not to be trusted download sites. Your solution is fully transparent and just works after a restart on my Win 10 machine. Thanks!

Comment: Easiest way to use the above: copy and paste the whole quoted grey text into a file named e.g. 'caps-lock-backspace.reg', then double click that file and click yes on the two prompts Windows gives you.

Comment: this is an amazing answer, thank you so much (and @HughW your comment was incredibly helpful too), but: is there a way to do this *and* make the backspace key be caps-lock?

Comment: @NicholasMontaño This command actually maps the Scroll Lock key to Caps Lock (which I think is great - now I have a Backspace for each hand and have replaced a useless key with one I actually use now and then). If you'd still like to map the Backspace key to Caps Lock instead, just replace the "46" with "0e".